# QuickBooks Online API error: message=No destination found for given partition key; errorCode=007001

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm using QuickBooks PHP dev kit and trying to set an invoice/customer, etc. I get this error message: **7001: [message=No destination found for given partition key; errorCode=007001; statusCode=400, ]**

What does it means? I've looked in the doc and didn't found a valuable answer for my situation.

Also, with QuickBooks PHP dev kit I get this error in *example_app_ipp_v3/*: **Fatal error: Call to a member function getCompanyName() on a non-object in XXXXX**

Is the second error related to the first one? Is there some missing informations?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In summery -

```
 Your QBO subscription expired or you're hitting SandBox company with a wrong base URL.
```

If you want to connect with existing QBO company, then you should use 'production tokens'.
'Dev tokens' can only be used with sandbox company.

For Sandbox company, correct base URL is - https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/

For more details, please have a look at the IPP's blog -

https://developer.intuit.com/v2/blog/2014/10/24/intuit-developer-now-offers-quickbooks-sandboxes

Thanks

Comment: Great! Could you tell the PHP file to change? There's no indication on the doc. I've looked in other websites, but there's nothing interesting related to this.

Comment: Manas -- we have an open support ticket with you (Case 00014843) for this exact same problem. We are NOT using a sandbox account. We ARE using production tokens. We ARE using the production URLs. We ARE using a normal production version of QuickBooks (not the sandbox). Why are we getting this error still? When will it be resolved?

Comment: It's a random problem, sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't, why?

Comment: @KeithPalmer-consolibyte - There are some issues due to recent changes. We had reported this to our DEV team. Please communicate over the support mail thread. We'll keep this thread updated. Sorry for the inconvenience. Thanks

Comment: So is the above answer incorrect then? If so, you should edit it to reflect the real problem here. In the future, will this particular error message indicate a cancelled subscription, or will it indicate an internal issue with QuickBooks itself?

Comment: No, it is not incorrect. The above ans suggests the general solution. There are couple of cases where users are finding issues. We'll update the post as soon as you get all these info.

Answer (score 2):

After some research, I've found the right file to change. If you use Keith Palmer's PHP DevKit, go to **/quickbooks-php/QuickBooks/IPP/IDS.php** and change URL_V3 **(https:// quickbooks.api.intuit.com/vx**) for (**https:// sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/vx**).

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

QB changed their sandbox testing account last week. You are seing the error because you have are hitting the main prod site instead of sandbox site.

Please read these url's

https://developer.intuit.com/v2/blog/2014/10/24/intuit-developer-now-offers-quickbooks-sandboxes & https://developer.intuit.com/v2/blog/2014/10/20/changes-to-ipp-app-tokens

In Java, I was able to solve this using config overlide as follows
Config.setProperty(Config.BASE_URL_QBO, "https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company");

Answer (score 1):

You need to submit a support ticket to Intuit for this. You can do that here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/Support/Incident

Usually this error means one of two things. Either:

- Your QuickBooks Online subscription has expired.

OR

- Intuit broke something on their end, and you need to submit a support ticket to them to get it fixed.

It is not a problem with your code, or with the DevKit code.

Answer (score 0):

QuickBooks Sandbox

Previously, Intuit provided you with 1 year developer subscriptions for QuickBooks Online for US, UK, AU and CA with no sample data included.  With the new developer experience, you now have a ready-to-use US-based sandbox company for your development and testing purposes which includes sample data.

We will continue to provide 1 year developer subscriptions for QuickBooks Online for UK, CA and AU and plan to enable sandboxes for these countries in future.

App Tokens

With the introduction of sandboxes, there have been some changes to app tokens.  Previously, your development app tokens could connect to any kind of QuickBooks Online account – trial subscriptions, paid subscriptions, or 1 year developer subscriptions.  You can now only connect your development app tokens to your single US sandbox.  There is no limit on the number of connections to your sandbox from your development app token.

To create a sandbox, please go to https://developer.intuit.com/ and sign in. At the bottom of the page, there is a link for QuickBooks sandbox. Just click on it and you will be set. You can manage your sandbox here.

To test your application against any kind of existing QuickBooks Online account, including your existing trial or 1 year developer subscription, you must switch your application to use production app tokens.  If you do not do this, you will get the following error:

Error code : invalid_database. Error message : Development application can only subscribe to sandbox company. No sandbox company found Error Id :

To summarize, development app tokens will work only for sandbox companies and production app tokens will work for all other cases. You do not need to publish your application to use your production app tokens.

URI Endpoints for QuickBooks Online API

Previously, the base url for QuickBooks Online was already configured in the SDK: https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/. However, to access a sandbox company from your application, you need to change base url for QuickBooks Online calls to- “https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/“;

If you do not make the change for base url for sandbox, you will get the following error-

Error code 7001: “message=No destination found for given partition key; errorCode=007001; statusCode=400″